# Could not find method jdependMain() for arguments

Tags: java, gradle, jdepend

I am trying to run JDepend plugin via gradle. I have following jdepend.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'jdepend'

// Repository definition to get JDepend libraries.
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

jdepend.reportsDir = file("${reporting.baseDir}/jdepend-output")

jdependMain {
    reports {
        text {
            enabled = 'true'
            destination = file("${jdepend.reportsDir}/jdepend.txt")
        }
        xml {
            enabled = !text.enabled
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to run build I have following error:

> gradle build -x test --parallel
>
> Parallel execution with configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where:
>     Script 'C:\Drive D\Dev\project\projectName\gradle\jdepend.gradle' line: 10
>
>   - What went wrong:
>       A problem occurred evaluating script.
>       Could not find method jdependMain() for arguments [jdepend_1dpftayagd693nuav7nmwvyci$_run_closure2@45128c37] on root project 'projectName' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
>   - Try:
>       Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 3.834 secs

Could you please help me to understand what's wrong? 
Thanks.

Regards,
Sergii

Answer (score 0):

I was applying JDepend plugin to the main project and it was the problem. I needed to apply it to all sub-projects instead.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific in how you fixed the error please?

Comment: I have a multi project build. So, instead of applying this plugin to a main project (like, to a whole gradle.build file) I had to do it for all sub-projects. Something like this:  

`def projectsWithArtifacts() {
    return subprojects.findAll {
        it.name.equals('webapp') || it.name.equals('core')
    }
}

configure(projectsWithArtifacts()) {
    apply from: "$rootProject.projectDir/gradle/jdepend.gradle"
}
`